# App Domain when using localhost for facebook authentication laravel 5.1

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

hello so im using socialite in laravel 5.1 and using it in localhost still and in also using xampp. When i click the login button i created it has an error just like this 
[image]

do i have to change the settings in my facebook dev settings? right now it looks like this
[image]

do i need to have changes on this?
on my `.env` file

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=xxxxx
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxx
CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost/<my projectname>/public/auth/facebook/callback
```

UPDATE:

hi so i also added `htpp://localhost/` in my app domain but i got some warning saying
[image]

ps: im using xampp.

any ideas what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: can you test localhost without http ? Just double confirm, is there any port like 8000 or something?

Comment: hi @KelvinKyaw will try it out. i dont have port number because i removed it before. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability, wrong configuration on FB developer dashboard or blank in App Domains Textbox or have you changed a URL's of an existing App?

You should recheck again under [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

1. Check correct App setting
2. Add App Domains in App Domains Box  Check
3. URL and path to your development environment

You can reference in [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain) and [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590243/using-laravel-socialite-to-login-to-facebook)

I'm not sure this step is related with yours. But, I tried to test according to your error message.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi! so i added the site url as `http://localhost/blog/public/` and in the app domain as same then it became `localhost` but i got a `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem:` any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add in the domain you run your website on your localhost (e.g. mysite.dev) into the "App Domains" box, it'll tell you what format to use. You can add in multiple domains here as well.

I'm not sure how running your project inside a folder will affect this (if at all), just try adding **localhost** into the box and tweak until it passes you back properly.

Comment: hi! i tried that but i got a warning (please see updated question). hmm im using xampp by the way

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/, go to your dashboard after logged in, go 'PRODUCTS'->facebook login->settings from the left, now under the 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs', make sure input this: YOUR APP URL/login/facebook/callback, save change.
It worked for me.