# How to redirect the user to login to facebook and have them come back to the same place?

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

I have a dashboard feature that requires facebook login. If the token is expired, I catch that.

*So far so good*, however, I'd like the user to go off to login and come back to the same place.

This is the code:

```
try {
    //make FB client
    $fb = new Facebook( [
        'app_id'                => config( 'app.FACEBOOK_APPID' ),
        'app_secret'            => config( 'app.FACEBOOK_APPSECRET' ),
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
    ] );

    //Pull events realted to this user
    $events      = $fb->get( $endpoint, $accessToken )->getDecodedBody();

//catch exception if token is expired
} catch ( FacebookSDKException $e ) {
    //redirect to facebook login
    return redirect()->action('Auth\SocialiteLoginController@redirectToProvider', ['facebook']);
}
return $events;
```

***My issue is***, the `return redirect()` statement, does not redirect the user to Facebook, but, it sends back the `RedirectResponse` object to the calling function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590243/using-laravel-socialite-to-login-to-facebook/30590747

Comment: I setup all of that. I need to redirect without return.

Answer (score 0):

Better use socialite drive it will handle objects.

Redirect to facebook driver

```
 return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
```

need to declare facebook redirect url in .env , facebook credentials page  and local route page also.

```
public function handleFacebookCallback(Request $request){
     $AccessToken = Socialite::driver('facebook')->getAccessTokenResponse($request->code);
        if($token = $AccessToken['access_token']){
                $facebook =Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($token);

        if($facebook->id){ 
        //insert process and get auth userkey 
        redirect('/login page');
         }else{
        redirect('/dashboard');  //not auth user
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-social-authentication-with-socialite  use step by step process