# FB login doesn't work, but FB share does with Laravel socialite

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite

I have implemented two social features in my Laravel application using Socialite: share and login.

I have the settings in .env and, correspondingly, in config/services.php:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI')
],
```

I have a Facebook share option for articles on the site and it works fine, taking the user to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.com/rest-of-url
```

The share dialog is there and the user can post to his wall correctly.

However, login with Facebook gives the following error:

```
Login Failed: You can't use Facebook to log into this app or website because there's an issue with its implementation of Facebook Login.
```

The URL that the user is directed to looks correct:

https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=https://example.com%2Fsocialite%2Flogin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=Vn8L1gcutzi3xbbHCxBr7lXltuLkMsnFkoG4dEtu

Does someone have any idea what could be wrong, or at least how to get a more meaningful error message to troubleshoot with?

EDIT: upon debugging after the callback, I see that I get a "400 unauthorized" error. But the client ID and client secret are correct, so what might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should check the following Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590243/using-laravel-socialite-to-login-to-facebook

Comment: Thanks. Seeing how I have all the required routes and settings, I suppose the natural conclusion is that it might be an issue on the "Facebook side" as one answer put it. Since my client owns the app, I will have to request access from him. Do you know if app ownership could have something to do with the issue?

Comment: @Hackerman also please see my edit above

Comment: Make sure you're logging in with a Facebook user that has some sort of role in the app - you should get debug details beyond "there's an issue with its implementation" if you're an admin, developer, or tester role in the application.