# The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID. laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook-apps, laravel-socialite

i'm trying to set up a login with facebook in laravel using socialite all goes right except in the last step i get "The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID" even app ID and secret id are correct

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'job_seeker\Login_Job_Seeker_Controller@redirectToProvider');
    Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'job_seeker\Login_Job_Seeker_Controller@handleProviderCallback');

public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        // $user->token;
        return $user->username;
    }


 'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('299264422458524'),  // Your Facebook App ID
        'client_secret' => env('298294cfcc04df22932151877e856522'), // Your Facebook App Secret
        'redirect' => env('http://127.0.0.1:8000/job_seeker/login/facebook/callback'),
    ]
```

,

Answer (score 4):

env() function takes two arguments. first is env key and the second is a default value.  in your `config/service.php` file add like this

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id'     => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI'),
],
```

and in your .env file Add

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=299264422458524
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=298294cfcc04df22932151877e856522
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8000/job_seeker/login/facebook/callback
```

Comment: now i get Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Comment: you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590243/using-laravel-socialite-to-login-to-facebook

Comment: i get blank page after logged in